# What's the name of the item that controls the color of http links inside string literals in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, customization

I am trying to change the color of the http links inside string literals in Visual Studio 2010, but neither String, not Literal doesn't control the color of them. They still appear blue.

For instance:

"http://mylink.com"

" characters appear in the color I set, but http://mylink.com still stays the same color which is blue.

What item in the Fonts and Colors customization of VS control this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item you are looking for is "URL Hyperlink".  Changing this will update the values in your code.

[image]

Comment: Ah well, fiddled too long with WindowClippings ;-)

Comment: Thanks alot, now found it. Will accept as an answer in 5 mins because of the time limit.